# Python Virtualenv HTTP Server With Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, virtualenv

Trying to host a python http server and works fine.

```
FROM python:latest
COPY index.html /
CMD python3 -m http.server
```

But when trying with python virtualenv, facing issues.

```
FROM python:3
COPY index.html .
RUN pip install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv --python="python3" .virtualenv
RUN .virtualenv/bin/pip install boto3
RUN python3 -m http.server &
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Please help.

Comment: please post the complete error so that others can help with the problem

Comment: http server isn't coming up and couldn't find anything in logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to point up that using `virtualenv` within docker container might be redundant.

With docker, you are encapsulating your one specific application along with its dependencies (libraries, frameworks, boto3 in your case), as opposed to your local machine where you might have several applications being developed, each with different dependencies.

Thus, I would recommend considering again the necessity of virtualenv within docker.

Second, running the command:

```
RUN python3 -m http.server &
```

in the background is also bad practice here. You want to run it with the `CMD` command in the foreground, so it will run as the first process (PID 1). Then it will receive all docker signals, and start automatically with the container start:

```
CMD ["virtualenv/bin/python3", "-m", "http.server"]
```